# Installing custom R package from bitbucket in Python through rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am using rpy2 package within Python. And I am looking for a way to install custom R package from bitbucket. I have been able to install same package with in R through

```
library(devtools)
install_bitbucket("myrepo", auth_user="xyz", subdir = "abc", password="123")
```

With in Python I am looking for something like this,if possible:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
devtool = rpackages.importr('devtools')
devtool.install_bitbucket("myrepo", auth_user="xyz", subdir = "abc", password="123")
```

Looking for help to correctly install the package and use its custom functions.
Thanks

Comment: the script you have provided should work just fine. if you have already installed a package, it will only reinstall the package if it has changed or if you use `force = TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

1. installing devtools through importing utils
2. Installing my package from bitbucket through importing devtools.

This may sound trivial but that's the best that I could come up with for now.
Here is the source code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
devtools = utils.install_packages('devtools')
d = {'package.dependencies': 'package_dot_dependencies',
     'package_dependencies': 'package_uscore_dependencies'}
custom_analytics = importr('devtools', 
                   robject_translations = d)
abc = custom_analytics.install_bitbucket("myrepo", auth_user="xyz", subdir = "abc", password="123")

abc = importr('abc', 
                   robject_translations = d)
```